# How to typeset Tibetan in XeLatex with correct linebreaks?

Tags: line-breaking, languages, unicode, hyphenation, polyglossia

I am trying to typeset Tibetan language in a document, but the text does not wrap at the margin. I think this could be easily fixed if I tell XeLaTeX to recognise the Tibetan tsheg character ('TIBETAN MARK INTERSYLLABIC TSHEG' U+0F0B) as a soft hyphen. Is there any way to set the soft hyphenation character within an environment?

Example code:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{fontspec} 
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\usepackage{xunicode} 
\usepackage{xltxtra} 
% \usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainfont{Cambria} 
\setsansfont{Calibri}

% \setotherlanguages{tibetan}
\newfontfamily\tibetanfont[Script=Tibetan,Scale=MatchUppercase]{MicrosoftHimalaya}

\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{letterpaper} 

\begin{document}

Test.

\begin{tibetanfont}
\noindent
༈ རང་གི་མདུན་གྱི་ཐད་དྲང་གི་ནམ་མཁའི་གནས་སུ་སེངྒེ་ཆེན་པོ་བརྒྱད་ཀྱིས་བཏེག་པའི་རིན་པོ་ཆེའི་ཁྲི་མཐོ་ཞིང་ཡངས་པའི་སྟེང་ཁར་སྣ་ཚོགས་པད་ཟླ་ཉི་མའི་དཀྱིལ་འཁོར་གྱི་གདན་ལ་ངོ་བོ་རང་གི་དྲིན་ཅན་རྩ་བའི་བླ་མ་ཡིན་པ་ལ་རྣམ་པ་རྒྱལ་བ་ཤཱཀྱ་ཐུབ་པ་སྐུ་མདོག་གསེར་བཙོ་མ་ལྟ་བུ་དབུ་གཙུག་ཏོར་དང་ལྡན་པ་ཞལ་གཅིག་ཕྱག་གཉིས་གཡས་ས་གནོན། གཡོན་མཉམ་བཞག་གི་སྟེང་ན་བདུད་རྩིས་གང་བའི་ལྷུང་བཟེད་བསྣམས་པ། སྐུ་ལ་ཆོས་གོས་ངུར་སྨྲིག་གོ་མདོག་ཅན་གསོལ་བ། མཚན་དཔེས་བརྒྱན་པའི་དྭངས་གསལ་འོད་ཀྱི་རང་བཞིན་ཅན་སྐུ་ལས་སྐྱེད་པའི་འོད་ཀྱི་ཕུང་པོའི་དབུས་ན་ཞབས་གཉིས་རྡོ་རྗེ་སྐྱིལ་ཀྲུང་གིས་བཞུགས་པ། དེ་ཉིད་ཀྱི་མཐའ་སྐོར་དུ་དངོས་དང་བརྒྱུད་པའི་བླ་མ་ཡི་དམ་སངས་རྒྱས་བྱང་སེམས་དཔའ་བོ་མཁའ་འགྲོ་ཆོས་སྐྱོང་སྲུང་མའི་ཚོགས་རྣམས་ཀྱིས་བསྐོར་ནས་བཞུགས་པ། དེ་དག་རང་རང་གི་མདུན་ན་གདན་ཁྲི་ཕུན་སུམ་ཚོགས་པ་ལ་རང་རང་གིས་གསུངས་པའི་ལུང་གི་ཆོས་རྣམས་འོད་ཀྱི་རང་བཞིན་ཅན་གྱི་པུ་ཏིའི་རྣམ་པར་ཡོད་པ།
\end{tibetanfont}

Test.

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your minimal working example is really good already, but you could boil it down a little further as I described at [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225). Also, I’m getting a number of meaningful of meaningful `polyglossia` warnings when I compile your code, could you add those to your question? I hope somebody will provide a solution here – the Tibetan script sure looks beautiful!

Comment: The polyglossia errors were because there are no hyphenation rules for Tibetan, and the polyglossia documentation in TexLive 2012 doesn't explain how to write polyglossia rules. If the language 'Tibetan' with hyphenation rules were added to the polyglossia package, I could then use `\setotherlanguage` from the polyglossia package to apply them. However I can't do that, so I'm wondering of there is a way to set them in the environment.

Comment: Can you break at ་ (TIBETAN MARK INTERSYLLABIC TSHEG)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no support for Tibetan in Polyglossia. However you can use the TIBETAN MARK INTERSYLLABIC TSHEG as a hyphen mark (not soft, I'm afraid).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{geometry} 

\usepackage{fontspec} 
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\tibetanfont[Script=Tibetan,Scale=MatchUppercase,
  HyphenChar="0F0B]{Kailasa}
\newenvironment{tibetan}
  {\par\tibetanfont\raggedright}
  {\par}

\begin{document}

Test.

\begin{tibetan}
\noindent
༈ རང་གི་མདུན་གྱི་ཐད་དྲང་གི་ནམ་མཁའི་གནས་སུ་སེངྒེ་ཆེན་པོ་བརྒྱད་ཀྱིས་བཏེག་པའི་རིན་པོ་ཆེའི་ཁྲི་མཐོ་ཞིང་ཡངས་པའི་སྟེང་ཁར་སྣ་ཚོགས་པད་ཟླ་ཉི་མའི་དཀྱིལ་འཁོར་གྱི་གདན་ལ་ངོ་བོ་རང་གི་དྲིན་ཅན་རྩ་བའི་བླ་མ་ཡིན་པ་ལ་རྣམ་པ་རྒྱལ་བ་ཤཱཀྱ་ཐུབ་པ་སྐུ་མདོག་གསེར་བཙོ་མ་ལྟ་བུ་དབུ་གཙུག་ཏོར་དང་ལྡན་པ་ཞལ་གཅིག་ཕྱག་གཉིས་གཡས་ས་གནོན། གཡོན་མཉམ་བཞག་གི་སྟེང་ན་བདུད་རྩིས་གང་བའི་ལྷུང་བཟེད་བསྣམས་པ། སྐུ་ལ་ཆོས་གོས་ངུར་སྨྲིག་གོ་མདོག་ཅན་གསོལ་བ། མཚན་དཔེས་བརྒྱན་པའི་དྭངས་གསལ་འོད་ཀྱི་རང་བཞིན་ཅན་སྐུ་ལས་སྐྱེད་པའི་འོད་ཀྱི་ཕུང་པོའི་དབུས་ན་ཞབས་གཉིས་རྡོ་རྗེ་སྐྱིལ་ཀྲུང་གིས་བཞུགས་པ། དེ་ཉིད་ཀྱི་མཐའ་སྐོར་དུ་དངོས་དང་བརྒྱུད་པའི་བླ་མ་ཡི་དམ་སངས་རྒྱས་བྱང་སེམས་དཔའ་བོ་མཁའ་འགྲོ་ཆོས་སྐྱོང་སྲུང་མའི་ཚོགས་རྣམས་ཀྱིས་བསྐོར་ནས་བཞུགས་པ། དེ་དག་རང་རང་གི་མདུན་ན་གདན་ཁྲི་ཕུན་སུམ་ཚོགས་པ་ལ་རང་རང་གིས་གསུངས་པའི་ལུང་གི་ཆོས་རྣམས་འོད་ཀྱི་རང་བཞིན་ཅན་གྱི་པུ་ཏིའི་རྣམ་པར་ཡོད་པ།
\end{tibetan}

Test.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\XeTeXlinebreaklocale` and companion primitives should help as well.

Answer (score 4):

add `\XeTeXlinebreaklocale` "bo" after `\begin{document}`

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Microsoft Himalaya}
\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
\XeTeXlinebreaklocale "bo"
།།འདིར་སྨྲས་པ།
\begin{quotation}
 གལ་ཏེ་འདི་དག་ཀུན་སྟོང་ན། །འབྱུང་བ་མེད་ཅིང་འཇིག་པ་མེད།།གང་ཞིག་སྤང་དང་འགོག་པ་ལས། །མྱ་ངན་འདའ་བར་འགྱུར་བར་འདོད།
\end{quotation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm sure you will get right line-breaks.

Answer (score 1):

I gave an answer above yesterday. Through a new research of Polyglossia Package, I find out a new solution to Tibetan line-breaks. In fact, Polyglossia is supporting Tibetan now and I was totally misled by Tom who commented on this question. This is my example.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{eledmac}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{tibetan}
\setmainfont{Microsoft Himalaya}
\lineation{page}
\sidenotemargin{inner}
\linenummargin{outer}
\doublespacing
\begin{document}
\begin{tibetan}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
།།འདིར་སྨྲས་པ།
\begin{quotation}
 གལ་ཏེ་འདི་དག་ཀུན་སྟོང་ན། །འབྱུང་བ་མེད་ཅིང་འཇིག་པ་མེད།

།གང་ཞིག་སྤང་དང་འགོག་པ་ལས། །མྱ་ངན་འདའ་བར་འགྱུར་བར་འདོད། 25.1
\end{quotation}
།འདི་ན་བཅོམ་ལྡན་འདས་ཀྱིས་གང་ཟག་ཚངས་པར་སྤྱོད་པ་བསྟེན་ཞིང༌། དེ་བཞིན་གཤེགས་པའི་བསྟན་པ་ལ་ཞུགས་པ་ཆོས་རྗེས་སུ་མཐུན་པའི་ཆོས་ཀྱི་ནན་ཏན་དང་ལྡན་པ་རྣམས་ལ། མྱ་ངན་ལས་འདས་པ་རྣམ་པ་གཉིས་སུ་གསུངས་ཏེ། ཕུང་པོ་ལྷག་མ་དང་བཅས་པ་དང༌། ཕུང་པོ་ལྷག་མ་མེད་པའོ།
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{tibetan}
\end{document}
```

Result is as follows:
[image]

Comment: Downvoting an answer without leaving a comment just because it's outdated doesn't seem in line with the site's practice. You should have updated your answer, instead of adding a new one (and using `eledmac` seems completely out of place).